# Add Facebook App to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

All,
I created a facebook application in the developers.facebook.com. Then on the basic page under how it integrates with Facebook I select Page Tab. I supplied the information because I'm hosting the page and now I want to display it on my Facebook page.

How can I actually display this application on my facebook page?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: I was missing needing to add a Site URL. Once I did that your link above worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding as an answer for future reference:

Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs and make sure you've added all the fields necessary for the 'Add Page Tab' dialog to work; most likely the dialog will fail with Error 191 if you've included a `redirect_uri` field with a URL other than the one in your Page Tab Url or Site Url